# C# MongoDB BsonDocument not getting serialized to custom class using BsonSerializer

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bsondocument

I am having an issue with serializing BsonDocuments using BsonSerializer.

I am using `var bsonDoc = collection.Find(...)` to pull a single document from a MongoDB database.
I then try to serialize it using
`var strongTypedDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MainSDocument>(bsonDoc);`

Here is the BsonDocument

```
   { 
      "MainSPayload" : 
        { 
           "GDeets" : { "Id" : 0, "GSerial" : "XX123XX123" }
        }
   }
```

Here are the C# classes

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MainSDocument
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public MainState MainSPayload
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MainState 
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public GDetails GDeets
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class GDetails 
{
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string GSerial
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is: `FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the GDetails property of class MainState : Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class GDetails .'`

Why is this happening? Why doesn't the element `Id` match the int element `Id` in the `GDetails` class?

Comment: please show us the class `GroupInfo`

Comment: @Jazb oops! that was a typo :) corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization for `Id` field has a special workflow that effectively converts this value into how the server side represents it: `_id`. To workaround it you can use:

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<GDetails>(c =>
        {
            c.AutoMap();
            c.UnmapField(u => u.Id); // remove default _id workflow 
            c.MapField(u => u.Id); // add a simple Id field
        });
```

or simpler:

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<GDetails>(c =>
        {
            c.AutoMap();
            c.SetIdMember(null);
        });
```

**UPDATE**:
There is a bit more flexible way. You can configure a new convention and set for what types you will need using it:

```
        var customPack = new ConventionPack();
        customPack.Add(new NoIdMemberConvention());
        ConventionRegistry.Register("NoIdConvention", customPack, t => t == typeof(GDetails));
```

also instead the above, you can just add BsonNoId attribute to your class:

```
    [BsonNoId]
    public class GDetails
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string GSerial
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more generic way to set this for all Id fields without having to put those  5 lines of code for each class?

Comment: I don't think so, and it's required not for each class, only for cases where `Id` means not server side `_id`

Comment: See the above update

Comment: Thanks. The `BsonNoId` attribute is more elegant imo..